Docker engine does not start | docker desktop does not installed properly in windows
steps followed to install docker desktop in windows.
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/setup/install/windows-install/
downloaded : Docker Desktop for Windows - x86_64 .
For installation, I tried,

keep the both checkbox - use WSL instead of hyper-V recommeded ,
desktop icon
Docker desktop is not launched , looks like my machine doesnt have the wsl .
I tried wsl --install but still doesnt work.

secondly, I chose to go for hyper-v . tried starting docker engine with ,
settings -> check box with use WSL based engine. - doesnt help , engine failed to start.
tried resetting with default , and engine still failed to start , shows pop -up again of failure.
My system doesnt have the hyper-v virtual machine , and i tried enabling hyper-v with the help of chat gpt answer.
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All /All /LimitAccess /Restart
enabled and disabled both the commands ran in powershell , still doesnot help for docker desktop still auto closing.
desktop keep getting auto closed as well.

I tried a workaround which solves the issue with my machine configuration .

uninstall the docker if you have older version ,
download  https://docs.docker.com/desktop/setup/install/windows-install/  and install
uncheck the first checkbox ( use WSL than hyper -v recommended option)
install .
go to setting , click on the checkbox WSL engine.
But this time , the server is started for a few secs never before , and stopped.
Let's move to the workaround if you have similar config like : https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13638#issuecomment-2245569588.

1.now close the docker desktop.
2.open terminal

wsl --version

, machine has similar kernal version 5.15. and then proceeding with

wsl --install

and give username , password for ubuntu account creation .
3. open the docker desktop.
DOCKER enginer run perfectly good !,
docker engine will start normally every time you open docker desktop.
hope this helps few!
